# 'make of someone', 'demanded of someone' cause difficulties

Tags: grammar, meaning

Could you explain logical conjectures for preposition 'of' in highlighted words.
Why not 'make with Calvin' and  'demanded her mother'? I would like to here not just translations, but explanations to apply (of) it in other cases.

> But Meg was still not satisfied. And what do you **make of** Calvin? she
>   **demanded of** her mother

A Wrinkle in Time by Madeleine L'Engle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Make of" is a phrasal verb. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/phrasal-verbs 
To ask "What do you make of Calvin?" means you are asking what the other person's opinion of Calvin is. You need the "of" here because it's part of the verb. https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/make-of
You can say things like "What do you make of it?" "I don't make anything of it."

"She demanded her mother" means something quite different to "She demanded of her mother." The first would mean she wants to see her mother immediately. "I demand a new cup of coffee!" The second means she is demanding an answer of her mother; she is demanding her mother to supply her with her opinion of Calvin. In general, if you're demanding of someone/thing you're trying to get something from them/it, whereas if you merely demand something you're trying to get the thing itself.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of "make of", it's a set phrase (arguably a phrasal verb). In the case of "demanded", Meg is the subject of the verb, and the object is "what do you make of Calvin". The thing that Meg is demanding is to know what her mother makes of Calvin. Her mother is the indirect object of "demanded"; Meg is not demanding her mother.